# Getting do-while error

Tags: java, do-while

So, I prompt from user to enter variable. If variable smaller than 0 and bigger than 10. If user enter either <0 and >10, I want to ask from user to enter the number again. I enter 4 when asking time, it saying you entered wrong. But at second attempt it works well. For example: If I enter 25, it print message which is " you entered wrong." Why am I getting this message even my input is proper for condition at first attempt?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class abc{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{


    int velocity;
    int time;

    System.out.print("Enter the velocity");

    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

    velocity = sn.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Enter the time");

    time=sn.nextInt();


    do{

        System.out.println("you entered wrong format/d Please Try Again");

        time=sn.nextInt();

    }while(time<0 || time>10);

}
}
```

Comment: do-whiles always execute once no matter what.

Comment: I need to use it. Do you have any advice ?

Comment: Why do you *need* a do-while? It's not optimal in this case. Use a while.

Comment: Use `if` `else` instead of `do` for that part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following implementations (see the comments).

## do-while loop

```
// Assuming the time value is not valid.
boolean isValidTime = false;

do {
    System.out.println("Enter the time: ");
    time = sn.nextInt();

    if (time < 0 || time > 10) {
        System.out.println("You have entered invalid time value!");
    } else {
        // The time value is valid now!
        isValidTime = true;
    }
// While the time value is not valid…
} while (!isValidTime);
```

## while-do loop

```
// Assuming the time value is not valid.
boolean isValidTime = false;

// While the time value is not valid…
while (!isValidTime) {
    System.out.println("Enter the time: ");
    time = sn.nextInt();

    if (time < 0 || time > 10) {
        System.out.println("You have entered invalid time value!");
    } else {
        // The time value is valid now!
        isValidTime = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The author said in the comments that he must use a do-while loop. "I need to use it. Do you have any advice ?"

Comment: @dshus, thank you very much for the note! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The do while loop will always execute the do{}block.  In your case when you enter the first number it executes the do{} first so it prints the message.  At the second time, at the while {} block it actually checks hence you get the expected message.

Comment: If you do need to do "do while" loop then you can just simply create a flag and initialize counter=0; before doing system.out.println, check if flag is not 0, if it is then and only then print the statement.  you will have to increase the counter like this.  flag=0; do{
        if(flag!=0){
        System.out.println("you entered wrong format/d Please Try Again");
        } flag=1;
        time=sn.nextInt();

    }while(time<0 || time>10);

Comment: I meant to initialize flag=0 not counter=0.  also to say "increase the flag like this" not the counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter the time");
    time=sn.nextInt();
    if (time < 0 || time > 10)
        System.out.println("you entered wrong format/d Please Try Again");


}while(time<0 || time>10);
```

This prints "Enter the time", waits for input, and if the input is wrong, loops prints the wrong format message and prints a message asking for the time again.

This is because the do-while always executes the statement at least once.  So what you do is get an integer, check if it's valid, and if it's invalid, it will loop anyways, so print a "wrong format" message. Otherwise, it will continue without printing the "wrong format" message.

If you want to only print "Enter the time" once, just move that statement right before do.